# Программирование игры в шашки

Tags: алгоритм

Я начал писать программу для игры в шашки. Обычно шашечные игры программируют алгоритмами на основе неполного перебора (минимаксы и прочее). А есть ли другие подходы (реально программируемые), которые не требуют перебора и хорошо играют?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует подход на основе нейронных сетей с памятью. Можете почитать на страничке [Jürgen Schmidhuber'a](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/rnn.html). Там есть публикация, посвященная [программированию игры в Go](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/cig2008go.pdf). Но, прямо скажем, это вещи далеко не простые и ради учебного задания лучше за них не браться, а делать по старинке минимаксом.

Answer (score 1):

Для эндшпиля есть подход "от конечной позиции", он просто оптимальный.
Суть - в том, что программа отталкивается от класса "0" - позиций с победой одной из сторон (условно - белых). 
Далее генерируются все позиции, из которых существует ход в позицию класса "0" - это позиции класса "1", в которых белые побеждают в один ход.
Следующими отбираются все позиции, которые при любом ходе чёрных ведут к позициям класса "1" - это позиции класса "2" и т.д.

Если шашек с обеих сторон немного (например, в простые дамочные эндшпили), то удаётся расклассифицировать все позиции, кроме ничейных. А играть с табличкой выигрышных позиций просто:
1) Если позиция есть в табличке, то надо её переводить в позицию класса на единичку меньше (выигрывающему - потому, что быстрее не получится, а проигрывающему - чтобы продлить сопротивление);
2) Если позиции нет в табличке, то надо не попасть своим ходом в эту табличку. Потому что из ничьей можно попасть только в проигрыш.

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно советуют выше, используй классику. Плюс к тому же, генерируй эндшпильные базы, программа станет гораздо умнее